# Validate if render referenceBlock in checkout layout

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, condition, validate

I have tried validate if render referenceBlock in checkout layout, but it does not work.

I added block Vendor\Module\Block\Index in layout after referenceBlock

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <block class="ElTiempo\Efecty\Block\Index" name="is_book">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- merge payment method renders here -->
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="efecty" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/payment/method-renderer</item>
                                                                    <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="efecty" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

In block validate if render with _toHtml() method

> Vendor/Module/Block/Index.php

```
namespace ElTiempo\Efecty\Block;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * Render block HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $isBook = true;

        if ($isBook) {
            return parent::_toHtml();
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

Any ideas would be the error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with official documentation and another answer:

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/frontend/custom-checkout/customize-view/

For remove a component in checkout layout xml first create a block LayoutProcessor implementing the \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface interface with process method (LayoutProcessorInterface::process($jsLayout))

> Vendor/Module/Block/Checkout/OurLayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface;

class OurLayoutProcessor implements LayoutProcessorInterface
{
    /**
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function process($jsLayout)
    {
        unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['renders']['children']['efecty']);
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Then create Dependency Injection and add the layout processor

> Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Vendor\Checkout\Block\Onepage">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="layoutProcessors" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="ourLayoutProcessor" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout\OurLayoutProcessor</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

I hope someone can use this answer

Greetings!